# Extremely low volume on headphones after jack repair

Tags: soldering, resistance, headphones

My headphones all of a sudden stopped working in one ear, then both. Same old story, I cut open the plug saw 5 wires (it's a TRRS plug, mic and button + headphones). The wires are

1. Red (Right Of course)
2. Blue (Left of course)
3. Golden (ground of course)
4. Green (no clue)
5. Golden and Blue twisted together (no clue)

Just to start off, I stripped the wires, **burned the enamel coating**, and re-soldered the Red, Blue and Golden wires to old jack only as below-
***P.S - picture just for reference***
[image: plug wiring]

1. Blank
2. Ground
3. Red
4. Blue

Plugging in the headphones to my laptop (which has a combo 3.5mm jack) I can hear sound on both earcups, but the sound is extremely low. My soldering is pretty shabby, so I'm suspecting that my bad soldering has increased the resistance so much that sound is low, but I'm not sure.

Why is the volume so low and how may I fix it?

Comment: You should check the resistance between each end of the wires, in case the wire itself is broken inside. If the resistance measurements are all low then check the resistance between the wires and the barrel. Or it might be simpler to do those checks in the reverse order if it is difficult to get to the headphone end of the wires.

Comment: Why don't you check the impedance with a volt meter (a good one and make sure you account for contact resistance) most manufacturers will list the headphone impedance.

Comment: @laptop2d I tried, but my meter didn't show up anything

Comment: Shouldn't the GND wire be connected to pin1 (the most outer)?

Comment: @Naz Idk... I gave up on those headphones and threw them in the trash...

Comment: Check the impedance from the trash bag to the flux capacitor.

Comment: @SaraHeart that trash bag has gone way beyond my reach now I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

I just have fixed such issue several days ago. Most probably you have issue with ground wire being broken. Sound is low level because now, without ground wire, you have two speakers connected in series.

Comment: So I just strip the ground wire a but more, burn the enamel and sold it again right?